# Unable to save dataframe on HDFS for Informix database

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, informix

We are able to connect Informix database with driver com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.
However, we are unable to save the dataframe on HDFS for any table, but we are able to print schama for any table.

Have tried below code:

```
    val informix = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> "urlname",
    "user" -> "username",
    "password" -> "xxxxx",
    "dbtable" -> "tablename",
    "driver" -> "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
    ).option("inferSchema", "false").option("nullValue","null")).load()

    informix.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("pathname")
```

We are getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException:systemerror:java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

We are having colum name contains Integer data values in source. However, we want to store on HDFS without considering the datatype? Please suggest ways to save to save the DF on HDFS.

Comment: Have you seen this issue on the spark csv package: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/239?

Comment: Thanks for your response,  yes tried that already prior to posting this question but unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: If possible let me know if you know any other solutions.